# What exactly build architecture, valid build architecture means?

Tags: ios, iphone, architecture

Can somebody explain me the exact significance of the following fields (in image) in Xcode? 
[image]

Specifically, what does Build active architecture and its debug and release option means? How should I set them?

Error I get is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the option to only build for the currently active architecture for Debug builds (building less is faster) while still building for all architectures for the Release build.

"Debug" and "Release" are qualifiers for the build process, and you can set up two different values for most build configuration options (for most options, a single setting is fine for both).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but its still not clear to me. I am building an app for iPhone4,5,6,6P and iPads. I am selecting above settings and architecture Armv7 covers all devices's instruction set including iPhone 6, as per apple documentations. But I am still unable to run it on iPhone 6 device. Its working fine on all other devices. Can you give me any link which can elaborate this?

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: I am getting this error after installing ad-hoc build on iPhone 6, this build works fine on every other device.
"Couldn't Load this file" @Thilo I have uploaded image above, showing error.